# Zipline - csv file

Tags: python, pandas, zipline

I am trying to figure out how to use my own csv datafiles (originally from Yahoo finance) to be used within Zipline. I know you need to load the csv file into a pandas dataframe. But I can't seem to stop Zipline from downloading the data from Yahoo.

My csv file format:

```
Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume, AdjClose
```

My algofile:

```
from zipline.api import order, record, symbol
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('AAPL.csv')

def initialize(context):
    pass

def handle_data(context, data):
    order(symbol('AAPL'), 10)
    record(AAPL=data[symbol('AAPL')].price)
```

My command line to create the pickle file:

```
run_algo.py -f E:\..\Main.py --start 2011-1-1 --end 2015-1-1 -o buyapple_out.pickle
```

Command line output:

```
[2015-03-27 10:18:20.809959] WARNING: Loader: No benchmark data found for date range.
start_date=2015-03-27 00:00:00+00:00, end_date=2015-03-27 10:18:19.973911, url=http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?a=2&s=%5EGSPC&b=27&e=27&d=2&g
=d&f=2015&c=2015
[2015-03-27 10:20:05.811965] INFO: Performance: Simulated 504 trading days out of 504.
[2015-03-27 10:20:05.811965] INFO: Performance: first open: 2013-01-02 14:31:00+00:00
[2015-03-27 10:20:05.811965] INFO: Performance: last close: 2014-12-31 21:00:00+00:00
```

My pickle file is created correctly. But it appears to still be using yahoo instead of my csv because the command line output talks about yahoo finance.
There seems to be no documentation from Zipline on how to do this, other than 'load the csv into a dataframe'. What else?

Many thanks.

Comment: [zipline is some kind of trading library](https://github.com/quantopian/zipline)

Comment: Not sure if you are asking a question or making a statement. But yes it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your issue is how you are using the data, not in how you are reading it in.   Here's a sample strategy using Bollinger Bands.

```
import pandas as pd
import locale
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from zipline.algorithm import TradingAlgorithm
import zipline.finance.trading as trading
from zipline.utils.factory import load_from_yahoo
from datetime import datetime, date
from pytz import timezone
import pytz
from dateutil.tz import tzutc
from dateutil.parser import parse
from zipline.finance.slippage import FixedSlippage
from zipline.finance.commission import PerShare, PerTrade


central = timezone('US/Central')
HOLDTIME = 5
locale.setlocale( locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
COMMISSION=0.005

def date_utc(s):
    return parse(s, tzinfos=tzutc)


class BollingerBands(TradingAlgorithm):   

    def initialize(self):
        self.invested       = False

        self.trade_size=1000
        self.long = False
        self.short = False
        self.closed = False
        self.trading_day_counter = 0  
        self.pct_stop = 0.025
        self.long_stop_price =  0.0
        self.short_stop_price=0.0
        self.target=0.05
        commission_cost = self.trade_size * COMMISSION
        self.set_slippage(FixedSlippage(spread=0.10))  
        self.set_commission(PerTrade(cost=commission_cost))  

    def handle_data(self, data):


        if data['Close'].price >= data['upper'].price and not self.invested:
            self.order('Close', self.trade_size)
            self.long_stop_price =  data['Open'].price - data['Open'].price * float(self.pct_stop) 
            self.short_stop_price =  data['Open'].price + data['Open'].price * float(self.target)
            self.long = True
            self.closed=False
            self.invested = True
            self.trading_day_counter = 0  
        if data['Close'].price <= data['lower'].price and not self.invested:
            self.short_stop_price =  data['Open'].price + data['Open'].price * float(self.pct_stop)
            self.long_stop_price =  data['Open'].price - data['Open'].price * float(self.target) 
            self.order('Close', -self.trade_size)
            self.short = True
            self.closed=False
            self.invested = True
            self.trading_day_counter = 0  
        if self.invested and (data['Close'].price <=  self.long_stop_price or data['Close'].price >=  self.short_stop_price): #or self.trading_day_counter == HOLDTIME):

            if self.long: 
                self.order('Close', -self.trade_size)
             if self.short:
                self.order('Close', self.trade_size)

            self.closed=True
            self.long=False
            self.short=False
            self.invested=False


        self.trading_day_counter =  self.trading_day_counter +1
        self.record(Close=data['Close'].price,
                    upper=data['upper'].price,
                    lower=data['lower'].price,
                    long=self.long,
                    short=self.short,
                    holdtime=self.trading_day_counter,
                    closed_position=self.closed,
                    shares=self.trade_size)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df=pd.read_csv('SPY.csv') # contains Date, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume


    df['avg'] = pd.rolling_mean(df['Close'], 21)
    df['std'] = pd.rolling_std(df['Close'], 21)
    df['upper'] = df['avg'] + 2 * df['std']
    df['lower'] = df['avg'] - 2 * df['std']
    df = df.dropna()

    # # # # init Strat Class
    Strategy = BollingerBands()
    # #print df

    # # # # # # Run Strategy
    results = Strategy.run(df)
    results['algorithm_returns'] = (1 + results.returns).cumprod()


    results.to_csv('output.csv')
    print results['algorithm_returns'].tail(1)[0]*100
```

Comment: I have used the above code to use a custom data source in the algorithm. The data source contains the date, open, high, low, close, volume.



However I get en error:

 raise ValueError("Missing assets for identifiers: %s" % missing)
ValueError: Missing assets for identifiers: ['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume', 'avg', 'std', 'upper', 'lower']

How could I begin to resolve this? Thanks